# How to get form validation error for Fileupload through Ajax in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to get the form_error for input type file in CodeIgniter.I wrote a code in Javascript that uses Ajax to pass the details as per below

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var des = $("#des").val();
var img=$("#file").prop('files')[0];
var fd=new FormData();
fd.append('photo',img);
fd.append('name',name);
fd.append('description',des);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>personadd",
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And inside my Controller I have code as follows:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Person Name','trim|required',array('required'=>'Please Enter %s'));
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description','Description','trim|required',array('required'=>'Please Enter %s'));
if(!isset($_FILES['photo']['name'])) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('photo','Image','required',array('required'=>'Please select an %s'));
}
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE) {
    echo json_encode(['name'=>form_error('name'),'description'=>form_error('description'),'file'=>form_error('photo')]);
}
```

When execute this I am not getting the form_error for file.Please help me to solve this

Comment: <?php echo validation_errors(); ?> 
reference -> https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#the-form

Comment: What do you expect and what are you getting? What does the encoded array look like when validation fails?

Comment: my console output like this when validation fails    {"name":"<p>Please Enter Person Name<\/p>","description":"<p>Please Enter Description<\/p>","file":""}, i want validation error for file type when not selected any file

Comment: ok can you do a `print_r($_FILES);` before setting the rules, and an `echo validation_errors();` before echo json_encode(...     ... What is the result?

Comment: prin_r output is a blank array like,

Array
(
)

and for validation_errors() 

<p>Please Enter Person Name</p>
<p>Please Enter Description</p>

Comment: If the output of the array is blank that means 100% that the validation rule in the isset condition is getting set because there are no uploaded files and you should 100% be getting the form_error. I've confirmed that there is nothing wrong with your code in my version of CI running the following code: https://pastebin.com/TVtT5qwF.. When an image is set I get no file error, and when it isn't set I get a file error as expected. I'm sorry but I don't know why you are experiencing it and im not.

Comment: Thank you Alex,I just solved the problem by assigning an error message to a variable

Comment: So add an answer here, explain us what and how you solved it please !

Comment: improving readability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just modified the controller and solved the problem

```
if($_FILES['photo']['error']!=0)
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('photo','Photo','callback_filecheck');

}
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
{
    echo json_encode(['name'=>form_error('name'),'description'=>form_error('description'),'photo'=>form_error('photo')]);
}
```

and the callback function is

```
public function filecheck()
{
     $this->form_validation->set_message('filecheck', 'Please select {field}');
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below method

```
if(validation_errors())
{
    echo json_encode = validation_errors();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Neetin,i just solved the issue

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer and tell us what the code does?

Comment: Sorry to add my answer,i added my answer

Comment: it show validation in json formate if you want in json